# Process CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, jython

I have here a CSV file which contains a series of properties and values for some servers we have at work.

Here's a short sample:

```
Asset_ID     PropSVC     PropSVN     PropTSC     PropTSN
------------------------------------------------------------
A0001        SVC001      N032        TSC538      TS_BLAH
A0002        SVC002      N384        TSC002      TS_BLAH
A0006        SVC1223     N456        TSC002      TN_foo
A0006        SVC1223     N456        TSC004      T_Bar
```

As you can see, there are some servers (Indexed by their Asset ID) with duplicate entries and thus different properties. Some servers may not be duplicated in adjacent rows but spread all over the file, but I don't think this would pose an issue. 
What I'd like to do is to extract data from here and create a file such as the following, using Jython 2.7:

```
Asset_ID     Property     Value
----------------------------------
A0001        PropSVC     SVC001
A0001        PropSVN     N032
A0001        PropTSC     TSC538
A0001        PropTSN     TS_Blah
A0002        PropSVC     SVC002
A0002        PropSVN     N384
A0002        PropTSC     TSC002
A0002        PropTSN     TS_Blah
A0006        PropSVC     SVC1223
A0006        PropSVN     N456
A0006        PropTSC     TSC002, TSC004
A0006        PropTSN     TN_foo, T_Bar
```

Which is basically a list of each server's properties and their value or values if more than one and they are not the same. This way, the file gets smaller and easier to use as input for another software we will be using.

Are there any functions or ways to accomplish this in a relatively fast way?

Comment: There are a lot of ways. What have you tried and what is your specific question, what problem have you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets assume your CSV file is named `data.csv`, is tab-delimited, and contains:

```
A0001        SVC001      N032        TSC538      TS_BLAH
A0002        SVC002      N384        TSC002      TS_BLAH
A0006        SVC1223     N456        TSC002      TN_foo
A0006        SVC1223     N456        TSC004      T_Bar
```

Identify the columns:

- *Asset_ID* is `0`.
- *PropSVC* is `1`.
- *PropSVN* is `2`.
- *PropTSC* is `3`.
- *PropTSN* is `4`.

Record these as:

```
ID_COLUMN = 0 # Asset_ID
PROP_COLUMNS = [
    ('PropSVC', 1),
    ('PropSVN', 2),
    ('PropTSC', 3),
    ('PropTSN', 4),
]
```

I'm assuming your data is tab-delimited, so you would parse it with:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter='\t')
```

Without any processing, the data would look like this when parsed:

```
['A0001', 'SVC001', 'N032', 'TSC538', 'TS_BLAH']
['A0002', 'SVC002', 'N384', 'TSC002', 'TS_BLAH']
['A0006', 'SVC1223', 'N456', 'TSC002', 'TN_foo']
['A0006', 'SVC1223', 'N456', 'TSC004', 'T_Bar']
```

Now you want to aggregate the property values by the asset ID and property:

```
import collections
data = collections.defaultdict(set)
for row in reader:
    asset_id = row[ID_COLUMN]
    for prop, column in PROP_COLUMNS:
        prop_value = row[column]
        data[(asset_id, prop)].add(prop_value)
```

The aggregated `data` now looks like:

```
{('A0001', 'PropSVC'): set(['SVC001']),
 ('A0001', 'PropSVN'): set(['N032']),
 ('A0001', 'PropTSC'): set(['TSC538']),
 ('A0001', 'PropTSN'): set(['TS_BLAH']),
 ('A0002', 'PropSVC'): set(['SVC002']),
 ('A0002', 'PropSVN'): set(['N384']),
 ('A0002', 'PropTSC'): set(['TSC002']),
 ('A0002', 'PropTSN'): set(['TS_BLAH']),
 ('A0006', 'PropSVC'): set(['SVC1223']),
 ('A0006', 'PropSVN'): set(['N456']),
 ('A0006', 'PropTSC'): set(['TSC002', 'TSC004']),
 ('A0006', 'PropTSN'): set(['TN_foo', 'T_Bar'])}
```

Now let's save this data to `output.csv`:

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh, delimiter='\t')
    for (asset_id, prop), prop_values in data.iteritems():
        prop_values = ", ".join(prop_values)
        writer.writerow([asset_id, prop, prop_values])
```

This will create the tab-delimited file `output.csv` containing:

```
A0001     PropSVC     SVC001
A0001     PropSVN     N032
A0001     PropTSC     TSC538
A0001     PropTSN     TS_BLAH
A0002     PropSVC     SVC002
A0002     PropSVN     N384
A0002     PropTSC     TSC002
A0002     PropTSN     TS_BLAH
A0006     PropSVC     SVC1223
A0006     PropSVN     N456
A0006     PropTSC     TSC002, TSC004
A0006     PropTSN     TN_foo, T_Bar
```

NOTE: If you're running Jython 2.5, you'll need to add `from __future__ import with_statement` to the top of your script or replace all `with open(...) as fh` with `fh = open(...)`.